# Generate n colors between two colors

Tags: java, algorithm, colors, rgb

I'm trying to write function, which can generate colors between two colors based on a given value. An example would explain it better..

Input ..

```
X : 1
Y : 0.5
Z : 0
```

The user gives any set of `color:value` pairs, then enters a number(say 0.75). I have to then generate color which is a blend of Y and Z in proportion(based on the their values and the input value). I was thinking of the following approach.

- Find the colors which surround the value, for 0.75 it will be 0.5 and 1.
- Mix those two colors somehow, based on the value and generate new colors.

I'm completely lost, as how to generate colors and are there any libraries for this.

**UPDATE**: 
It is part of a bigger project I'm working on. Lets say we have ..

```
1 : X
0 : Y
```

and the user inputs, 0.25

I would like to have something..

```
(X*0.25 + Y*0.75)
```

as it's more near to Y, that's why the higher proportion. If the user inputs, 0.5.. the output should be

```
(X*0.5 + Y*0.5)
```

and so on. I have no idea how to do this with RGB colors.

P.S: The questions is not specific to language, but I'm doing this in Java.

Comment: Can you share some more example input and corresponding output ?

Comment: I don't think that the mixing will be unique. 0.25 = 1/4 red + 3/4 green or 1/2 * yellow + 1/2 green. Try having the weights in proportion like a three digit number where abc, where a is the weight of red, b green and c yellow?

Comment: Added some more details.

Comment: I think you need to read up on additive color mixing in general, and perhaps it might be useful to know that there are other color spaces available that might be easier to work with for a given task (eg. HSB/HSV). `java.awt.Color` is worth looking at.

Comment: `Red : 1
Green : 0
Yellow : 0.5`  You realize that colors are RG**B** not RG**Y**, right?  BTW - I'd use the quick'n'dirty approach of drawing a gradient to a `BufferedImage`, then obtaining the intermediate color from the image.

Comment: @sukunrt- Given two colors, associated with two values.. then generating a color based on a different value, which is between the two values.. should be unique.

Comment: @AndrewThompson- Yes, I do.. The user can give any set color:values, and then I have to generate based on that.

Comment: OK - I don't see how that input explains anything though.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - I apologize for not being clear. I changed my question a little bit. Is it any better now?

Comment: A little more clear, if you are working on a 3D plot. OTOH I'd use the technique mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: @AndrewThompson- Can you please explain your approach, maybe as an answer, if you would like to.

Answer (score 6):

You have to blend each color channel (red, green and blue) seperately like this:

```
Color x,y; //set by you
float blending;//set by you

float inverse_blending = 1 - blending;

float red =   x.getRed()   * blending   +   y.getRed()   * inverse_blending;
float green = x.getGreen() * blending   +   y.getGreen() * inverse_blending;
float blue =  x.getBlue()  * blending   +   y.getBlue()  * inverse_blending;

//note that if i pass float values they have to be in the range of 0.0-1.0 
//and not in 0-255 like the ones i get returned by the getters.
Color blended = new Color (red / 255, green / 255, blue / 255);
```

So far for the color example. Generally if you want a **linear interpolation** between two values you have to do the following:

```
var firstValue;
var secondValue;
var interpolation;

var interpolated =  firstValue * interpolation + 
                   secondValue * (1 - interpolation);
```

But since you have `Color-Objects` in your case, you cannot interpolate the whole object in one step, you have to interpolate each relevant value on its own. Eventually you have to interpolate the `alpha-channel` as well, don´t know that, since you didn´t mention it, but for completeness i include it in this answer.

Comment: This sounds like a good approach. I don't have the fourth channel, so it should not be a problem.

Answer (score 4):

A color is a point in a three-dimensional space. The exact coordinates used depend on what's called a "color space", of which there are several: RGB, HSV, and so on. So to compute a color in between two given colors, get those two colors in the same color space, and compute a third point between those two along the line in 3d-space between them.

The simplest way to do this would be simply to do a linear interpolation for each of the three values of the colorspace (R, G, and B, for example). But there's a further complication that the coordinate values are often not linear, so you have to linearize them first (for example, TV colors are exponential with a lambda of about 2.2). Depending on your application, incorrectly assuming linearity might work OK anyway, especially if the starting colors are already close.

(As mentioned by luk2302, add a fourth coordinate for alpha if necessary).

Comment: Are there any libraries for 3D interpolation, that sounds little hard to me.

Comment: Um, no, it's just a simple formula: 25% along the line from x0 to x1 is just (x0 + (.25 * (x1 - x0))). Just do it three times.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Java.awt.color by doing somting like this:

```
public Color mixColors(Color color1, Color color2, double percent){
      double inverse_percent = 1.0 - percent;
      int redPart = (int) (color1.getRed()*percent + color2.getRed()*inverse_percent);
      int greenPart = (int) (color1.getGreen()*percent + color2.getGreen()*inverse_percent);
      int bluePart = (int) (color1.getBlue()*percent + color2.getBlue()*inverse_percent);
      return new Color(redPart, greenPart, bluePart);
}
```