# How to generate n colors between two colors android

Tags: android, color-scheme

I followed this reference link: [android color between two colors, based on percentage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414673/android-color-between-two-colors-based-on-percentage)

but here is it possible to get n number of colors without passing any percentage.

I have tried two ways :

starting color : (a,b,c) ending color : (d,e,f)
count is 24

1. I used this formula

(a+(d-a)/24, b+(e-b)/24, c+(f-c)/24), (a+2*(d-a)/24, b+2*(e-b)/24, c+2*(f-c)/24) and (a+3*(d-a)/24, b+3*(e-b)/24, c+3*(f-c)/24) etc...

but didn't work

My expected values:

```
0 : 96,76,252
    - 1 : 75,93,255         
    - 2 : 56,111,255              
    - 3 : 37,129,252
    - 4 : 21,146,241
    - 5 : 8,163,226
    - 6 : 0,179,208
    - 7 : 0,192,186
    - 8 : 0,204,163
    - 9 : 1,213,140
    - 10 : 12,220,117
    - 11 : 26,224,95
    - 12 : 45,225,76  
    - 13 : 68,224,61
    - 14 : 92,221,50
    - 15 : 119,216,43
    - 16 : 146,210,41
    - 17 : 173,204,45
    - 18 : 198,197,53
    - 19 : 222,190,66
    - 20 : 242,184,82                                          
    - 21 : 255,179,102
    - 22 : 255,176,123
    - 23 : 255,174,146
```

Comment: if you want 3 colours between (a,b,c) and (d,e,f), you want (a+(d-a)/4, b+(e-b)/4, c+(f-c)/4), (a+2*(d-a)/4, b+2*(e-b)/4, c+2*(f-c)/4) and (a+3*(d-a)/4, b+3*(e-b)/4, c+3*(f-c)/4)

Comment: Color interpolation seems to be already asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544157/generate-n-colors-between-two-colors

Comment: what is 4 here,is that n number of colors I want

Comment: 4 is n+1, where n is the number of colours you want to generate

Comment: but it didn't give exact values , I want like this:  0 : 96,76,252
1: 75,93,255
 2: 56,111,255
 3:  37,129,252
  4 : 21,146,241

    - 5 : 8,163,226

    - 6 : 0,179,208

    - 7 : 0,192,186

    - 8 : 0,204,163

    - 9 : 1,213,140

    - 10 : 12,220,117

    - 11 : 26,224,95

    - 12 : 45,225,76

    - 13 : 68,224,61

    - 14 : 92,221,50

    - 15 : 119,216,43

    - 16 : 146,210,41

    - 17 : 173,204,45

    - 18 : 198,197,53

    - 19 : 222,190,66

    - 20 : 242,184,82

    - 21 : 255,179,102

    - 22 : 255,176,123

    - 23 : 255,174,146

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear ; I gave you a sample of how to generate 3 colours between two set colours. I expected you to derive the generic formula for n from that sample. If you check my sample you'll see the point is to get the difference between the starting colour and the end one for each component of the RGB value, divide that by the number of colours you want to generate plus one and use that number as a step which will increase for each new colour. You might have to floor or ceil the resulting value if it doesn't give exact values, but that shouldn't be a problem if you're using integers

Comment: yes , but its showing wrong values .. I sent you some values in that I am expecting 24 colors between  96,76,252 and  255,174,146. When I calculate as per your formula. I didn't get 75,93,255 this value . I got 10.6, 80, 6

Comment: I have no idea how you came up with those colors. Why does the red component goes down to 0 up to the 8th colour but then goes back up to 255 ? I currently do not understand the logic behind your sequence of colours and therefore wouldn't be able to provide an algorithm to generate it

Answer (score 0):

You can get random color from a list of colors by this.

class RandomColorsPicker {
        private Stack changeColors, colors;

```
    public RandomColorsPicker() {
        colors = new Stack<>();
        changeColors =new Stack<>();
        changeColors.addAll(Arrays.asList(
                0xfff44336,0xffe91e63,0xff9c27b0,0xff673ab7,
                0xff3f51b5,0xff2196f3,0xff03a9f4,0xff00bcd4,
                0xff009688,0xff4caf50,0xff8bc34a,0xffcddc39
                )
        );
    }

    public int getColors() {
        if (colors.size()==0) {
            while(!changeColors.isEmpty())
                colors.push(changeColors.pop());
            Collections.shuffle(colors);
        }
        Integer color= colors.pop();
        changeColors.push(color);
        return color;
    }
}
```

and get color by using this

```
          RandomColorsPicker colors=new RandomColorsPicker();
            int color=colors.getColors();
            String hex = Integer.toHexString(color);
```

Comment: Not random colors, i need to generate between two colors like start color and end color and then I need to get in between n colors

Comment: So you need to pass percentage for getting colors like this 
new ArgbEvaluator().evaluate(0.75, 0x00ff00, 0xff0000);

Comment: where i need to call new ArgbEvaluator().evaluate(0.75, 0x00ff00, 0xff0000) . starting color : 96,76,252 ending color : 255,174,146 these are my colors

Comment: when you want to change color just pass a float number for getting different colors

Comment: here i want 12 colors between starting color and end color , by using that logic how can I get

Comment: You can use loops for getting 12 color and pass value each time as per your requirment like 

  float a=0.2f;
        for(int i=0; i<=12; i++){
            a=i+a;
            int color = (Integer) new ArgbEvaluator().evaluate(a, 0xFF00BDF7, 0xFF00F142);
            String hex = Integer.toHexString(color);
        }

Comment: My expected values:  0 : 96,76,252 1: 75,93,255 2: 56,111,255 3: 37,129,252 4 : 21,146,241 - 5 : 8,163,226 - 6 : 0,179,208 - 7 : 0,192,186 - 8 : 0,204,163 - 9 : 1,213,140 - 10 : 12,220,117 - 11 : 26,224,95 - 12 : 45,225,76 - 13 : 68,224,61 - 14 : 92,221,50 - 15 : 119,216,43 - 16 : 146,210,41 - 17 : 173,204,45 - 18 : 198,197,53 - 19 : 222,190,66 - 20 : 242,184,82 - 21 : 255,179,102 - 22 : 255,176,123 - 23 : 255,174,146

Comment: @Mounika please edit your original question to include the values you want to achieve and what you've tried so far, that will just help everyone else give better answers

Comment: we should not hardcode the values we need to get dynamically within that range